# call to iopl(3) ends with "Operation not permitted", even when running as root

Tags: permissions, io

On older systems you could call a function `int iopl(int level)` with argument level=3 to get a permission to perform raw I/O operations. On Debian this still works, but on Ubuntu 18, it always returns -1 with errno 1 (Operation not permitted) even when running the program as root.

Manual doesn't say anything about it, just that you need to be root to use it, which i am.

Anyone knows why this function was disabled in Ubuntu 18 and if there is a way how to enable it?

I would like to try it only for experimental and educational purposes.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html says _EPERM  The calling process has insufficient privilege to call iopl();
              the CAP_SYS_RAWIO capability is required to raise the I/O
              privilege level above its current value._ So maybe fiddle with that capability? Just a guess, though.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html says *Prior to Linux 3.7, on some architectures (such as i386), permissions were inherited by the child produced by fork(2) and were preserved across execve(2).  This behavior was inadvertently changed in Linux 3.7, and won't be reinstated.* so my guess is your debian was old & used an [very] old kernel  (what debian? & what kernel)

Comment: Uh oh, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man2/iopl.2.html: _"This call is mostly for the i386 architecture.  On many other architectures  it  does  not exist or will always return an error."_ Does 64bit Intel count as i386 architecture or is it already one of those many where it does not exist and always returns error?

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same problem when I use the function iopl(3). I think maybe you can try to disable secure boot from BIOS per [this Github issue](https://github.com/zamaudio/intelmetool/issues/20#issuecomment-751562837).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1270711)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  If turning off secure boot solved the issue for you, it would be helpful to state that explicitly in your answer.  It's implied that it worked for you, but the wording is vague.  Thanks!